# Option clash for package xcolor

Tags: pgfplots, color, incompatibility, package-options

I'm writing a report, and have a rather large table in my appendix. I'd like to emphasize some specific values by coloring some single cells. I'm trying to do it with xcolor. But receiving the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.17
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
[]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[table]
```

My preamble looks as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{modroman}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

And take out of my table

```
\begin{table}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
       \hline
   \cellcolor{green!25}D & x & D/$L_0$ \\
       \hline
   65 & 2600 & 0,417\\
       \hline
   60 & 2400 & 0,385\\
  \end{tabular}
 \caption{Bestemmelse af bølgehøjde}
 \label{tab:Q1}
\end{table}
```

Read some other questions asking more or less the same. And the answer to them seems to be a "collision" between packages. I have no idea how to find the problem.
So my question is:

1. Where is the "collision"?
2. How on earth would I have found it without help ?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Once you get the error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17
```

type "h" (without the quotation marks, for help) in the output console and you get

```
? h
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [table]
Adding the global options:
  ,table
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

So, you get an explanation of the problem and a possible solution. Doing as advised you prevent the clash:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article,table]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{modroman}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Now, the problem was that another package (`pgfplots`, in this case) had already loaded the `xcolor` package *without* options, so loading it after `pgfplots` with the `table` option produces the clash. One way to prevent the problem was already presented (using `table` as class option); another solution is to load `xcolor` with the `table` option *before* `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{modroman}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, both solutions works, now i just have the problem of the borders of the table being covered by the cellcolor :), I will do some poking around.

Comment: @MaltheEisum did you find a solution for this problem of the color reaching over the borders?

Comment: @white_gecko Are you sure `cellcolor` covers your border lines? It might also just be an issue of your PDF viewer that renders the table. You should see the lines when you zoom in.

Comment: I don't have the example with me at the moment, but as I recall the effect was very obvious and I can't imagine it was just a matter of the viewer.

Comment: how can I see what packages are adding `xcolor`? how was `pgfplots` identified in this case? thanks!

Comment: Do you get an answer but I wanna know as well@BogdanMihai

Answer (score 18):

Another way is to paste this line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
```

before

```
\documentclass{...}
```

as was already referenced [here!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627797/package-xcolor-error-undefined-color-darkgreen)

Comment: You're a True Hero!

Answer (score 1):

If you used `tikz` related package, then one way that works for my computer is to load the `xcolor` before `tikz`. Example:

**Correct**:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}% xcolor first

\begin{document}
{\color{SkyBlue} This is a test.}
\end{document}
```

***Wrong:***

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}% xcolor should be first
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
{\color{SkyBlue} This is a test.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This not only works on your computer, it is the suggested way to do this.

Comment: I thought this is an alternative way to say this is only a possible solution.  If it is not 
 a suitable expression, then I will edit.

Comment: No, I think it's fine. =)