# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor (for table)

Tags: packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Option clash for package xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor)

While trying to do this:`\usepackage [ table ]{ xcolor }` I get this error:

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

All the packages

```
\documentclass{article} % For LaTeX2e
\usepackage{nips12submit_e,times}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{float}                  
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}            
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage [ table ]{ xcolor }
\usepackage { hhline }
```

Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: @Ojwist Is the linked question one that answers your issue? If so, we will close this one as a duplicate. (Others: let Ojwist have a chance to answer before closing!)

Comment: The package `eso-pic` loads `xcolor` (without any option); in turn it's `nips12submit_e` that loads `eso-pic`, so you have to say `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` *before* `\usepackage{nips12submit_e}`. Note that loading of `a4wide` is deprecated (and also dubious, as the `nips` package sets the page geometry), while `subfigure` is obsolete.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Probably one package loads xcolor with no or other options before line 16. Either try to move the line `\usepackage [ table ]{ xcolor }` up, or put »table« into the document options: `\documentclass[table]{article}`.

Though, I did not test.

---

Edit 1:

Question is a duplicate: [Option clash for package xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor) . So despite my quick answer we have to close it.

---

Edit 2:

> The package eso-pic loads xcolor (without any option); in turn it's nips12submit_e that loads eso-pic, so you have to say \usepackage[table]{xcolor} before \usepackage{nips12submit_e}.

-- says Egreg

Comment: Moving it up worked, will accept this as soon as the site allows me to

Comment: Keks, you could add what I said in my comment about locating where the call to `xcolor` should go.