# Cellcolor - undefined control sequence

Tags: tables, color, cellcolor

What is wrong with this please?
I have error

```
! Undefined control sequence. Fit& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& \cellcolor
```

Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\textbf{Konvergence - MOST a BRITE}

\begin{table}[h!!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.45}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{r|S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]}

Fit&    1&  2&  3&  4&  5&  6&  7&  8&  9& \cellcolor{blue!25}10 &  11\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why `[h!!]` ? (the second `!` does nothing)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There are actually more problems with his table than that.

Comment: @JouleV "start at the very beginning" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load `table` option of `xcolor`, which loads `colortbl` containing `\cellcolor`, etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{Konvergence - MOST a BRITE}
\begin{table}[h!!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.45}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{r|S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]}
Fit&    1&  2&  3&  4&  5&  6&  7&  8&  9& \cellcolor{blue!25}10 &  11\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Btw why is your table so wide?

Comment: for column specifying consider shorter  `\begin{tabular}{r|*{11}{S[table-format=5.6,table-auto-round]}}` :-)

Comment: and your table is to wide that can be fit in text width.

Comment: This solution did not work for me, but I have a similar case to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Despite being correct in the causes, @user156344's solution did not help me. Further Googling lead me [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor):

The two solutions in that post are the following:

1. Add the command `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` on your preamble before `\documentclass`.
2. Add the option `table` directly in your `\documentclass`.