# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor for table

Tags: tables, bibtex, pdftex, color

I get the following `LaTeX Error` for the `xcolor` class.

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.109 \definecolor
{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
[prologue]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[table,xcdraw]
Adding the global options:
prologue,table,xcdraw
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

Now as it was suggested here, [Option clash for package xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor), I have already added `prologue,table,xcdraw` in the `documentclass`:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,prologue,table,xcdraw]{acmart}
```

But even after adding this to the `documentclass`, it still does not compile and I still get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.109 \definecolor
{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
[prologue]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[table,xcdraw]
Adding the global options:
prologue,table,xcdraw
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

A minimal working example is here:

ACM Proceedings Template `acmart.cls` file is here: https://controlc.com/4e9747ce

And you can create a file and just create a file `main.tex` and copy the following content and it will be failing:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,prologue,table,xcdraw]{acmart}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\title{Tile}

\author{Anonymous author(s)}

\maketitle

%%% add page numbers to make it easier for reviewers. Remove after paper is accepted.
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

text text text .....



\end{document}
\endinput
```

**Found one solution:
I see in the ACM template `acmart.cls` it has the following:**

```
\RequirePackage[prologue]{xcolor}
```

**So I have to modify the ACM default template `acmart.cls` with the following:**

```
\RequirePackage[prologue,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
```

**However, I really don't want to modify the ACM default template.
Is there any other option?**

Comment: The .log file says it: use `\documentclass[prologue,table,xcdraw,…]{…}`

Comment: I actually already tried that to no avail. Reflected that in the question as well.

Comment: Provide MWE which reproduce your problem. It seems that you load `xcolor` twice but with different options.

Comment: @Zarko added MWE

Comment: @Zarko found a solution. I have to modify the ACM default template. But really don't want to do it. Is there any other option?

Comment: Start your document with `\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}` and remove the `\usepackage[…]{xcolor}` line.