# Package problems with tikz-cd and xcolor

Tags: color, tikz-cd, package-options

I have a problem with some packages interfering (I think). I am working on a document where I both want to have a tikz diagram and a table with some of the cells colored. For the cell color, I use the xcolor package, which gave an error that I tried solving with what was said here: [Option clash for package xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor).

As is, the code works, but I want to use the commented out 'biasedstate' box, instead of simply typing 'biasedbox' as is done now (so where I define the tikzpicture, I want to replace
'biasedbox' with \usebox{\biasedstate}). However, simply uncommenting the code for the biasedstate box gives an error and I don't understand why.

I know that it has to do with the xcolor package because when I remove ',table' from the first line and remove \cellcolor{red!25}, the biasedstate box works fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt,A4paper,table]{article}%
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newsavebox{\fairstate}
\newsavebox{\biasedstate}

\sbox{\fairstate}{
    \begin{tabular}{|l r|}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Fair}} \tabularnewline
        \hline
        1: & 1/6\\
        2: & 1/6\\
        3: & 1/6\\
        4: & 1/6\\
        5: & 1/6\\
        6: & 1/6\\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
}
%\sbox{\biasedstate}{
%   \begin{tabular}{|l r|}
%       \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Biased}} \tabularnewline
%       \hline
%       1: & 1/10\\
%       2: & 1/10\\
%       3: & 1/10\\
%       4: & 1/10\\
%       5: & 1/10\\
%       6: & 1/2\\
%       \hline 
%   \end{tabular}
%}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1pt,looseness=1,auto]
        \matrix [matrix of nodes] {
            \node (fair) [shape=rectangle] {\usebox{\fairstate}};
            \node (biased) [shape=rectangle,right=of fair] {biasedbox};\\
        };
        \draw (fair) to [bend left] node [pos=0.55] {0.05} (biased);
        \draw (biased) to [bend left] node [pos=0.45] {$0.1$} (fair);
        \path[every node/.style={auto=false},every loop/.style={looseness=5}] 
        (fair) edge [loop left] node [midway] {0.95} ()
        (biased) edge [loop right] node [midway] {0.9} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tabularx}{300pt}{ccc}
    a&b&c\\
    d&e&\cellcolor{red!25}f
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Move your \sbox commands after \begin{document}. It is normally not a good idea to do typesetting in the preamble, various things aren't setup yet there.

Comment: Oh ok, that solved it. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments