# How to solve option clash for xcolor?

Tags: packages, option-clash

I use a bunch of packages. I eventually wanted to use `bashful` but now I have a clash with `xcolor`. How should I solve/investigate this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={165mm,250mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[xparse,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{bashful}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Here the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \usepackage
               {listings}
```

Comment: your error is in line 9. You only have to make an educated guess (or look in the log-file) which packages before are loading xcolor.

Comment: Indeed, the error will follow the include of xcolor. If I move the usepackage, the error is somewhere else. I've also read that xcolor must come before listings.

Comment: search the site for `option clash xcolor`.

Comment: I did. I found plenty of answers :(

Comment: Try loading the `[dvipsnames]` option as an option of `\documentclass`.

Comment: `xcolor` had to be before `tcolorbox`.

Comment: The error suggests you try to do load `xcolor` again with different options than other package did. It's very likely `dvipsnames` was not included before, hence the error. You could probably remove the line with `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`. However, you would need to follow @Bernard's suggestion to have access to `dvipsnames`.

Comment: did you try typing `h` as the message suggests, so that the system tells you which options clash, and suggests a fix?

Answer (score 1):

As @Zarko suggested in the comments, the error disappears (at least for me) if one loads `xcolor` before `tcolorbox`. Does this fix your problem? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={165mm,250mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[xparse,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{bashful}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

This error probably occurs because `tcolorbox` loads `xcolor` with spesific options if it is not loaded *before* the package.

Here is a similar problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83102/199568

Comment: Please elaborate a little more your answer, otherwise is just Zarko's (or Bernard's) comment written as an answer