# Latex Error: Option clash for package xcolor when I try and highlight a row for a table

Tags: errors, packages

While trying to do this`:\usepackage [ table ]{ xcolor }` I get this error:
Latex Error: Option clash for package xcolor

This is my preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}\singlespacing
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\input{Title}

\input{Introduction}

\input{Background information}

\input{Methodology}

\input{Raw Data}

\input{Proccessed Data}

\input{Results}

\input{Discussion}

\input{Limitations and Improvements}

\input{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

This is the table I want to highlight the first row with `\rowcolor{blue!10}`

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Full name of chemical compound & Chemical formula \\
\hline
Potassium Iodine & KI \\
\hline
Potassium Hydroxide & KOH \\
\hline
Sodium Thiosulfate & $\text{Na}_2\text{S}_2\text{O}_3$ \\
\hline
Sulfuric Acid & $\text{H}_2\text{SO}_4$ \\
\hline
Manganese (II) Sulfate & $\text{MnSO}_4$ \\
\hline
Starch Indicator Solution & $\text{C}_6\text{H}_{12}\text{O}_5$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\captionof{table}{Chemical names and respective formulas for Winklers Method}
```

Any idea what is the problem ?

Comment: Probably https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor will help.

Comment: Yes, TikZ loads `xcolor` by default so it's too late when the user loads it manually. The order of the two packages should be switched.

Comment: When I swap the packages around in the preamble the same error occurs. I'm not sure what the issue is perhaps there is another issue to be corrected.

Comment: @Gaussian123 `chemfig` is also loading `tikz`; put `xcolor` before `chemfig`. The linked question/answer is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

Let me resume comment to question:

- each package should be load only once
- some package load other packages too: for example `tikz` load `xcolor` without options
- if in such cases you need option for loaded package, you should load it before its implicite loading.
- In your example you load `caption` twice and `xcolor` once by `tikz` and once with option `table` explicitly after `tikz`.
- Off-topic: for chem formules I would use `mhchem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.65in]{geometry}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % should be loaded only once

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % observe order
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!10}
Full name of chemical compound
                    & Chemical formula \\
    \hline
Potassium Iodine    & KI            \\
    \hline
Potassium Hydroxide & \ce{KOH}      \\
    \hline
Sodium Thiosulfate  & \ce{Na2S2O3}  \\
    \hline
Sulfuric Acid       & \ce{H2SO4}    \\
    \hline
Manganese (II) Sulfate  
                    & \ce{MnSO4}    \\
    \hline
Starch Indicator Solution 
                    & \ce{C6H12O5}  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Chemical names and respective formulas for Winklers Method}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]